# pandas dataframe assign random numbers group by

Tags: python, pandas

I want to randomly assign numbers to a given dataframe grouped by col1 so :

```
col1   col2 
MLB    1
MLB    1 
NBA    2
NFL    3
NFL    3
NFL    3
```

However, my script will go through multiple dataframes and I dont want MLB to always be associated with 1 so the next time it would output something like this.

```
col1   col2 
MLB    3
MLB    3 
NBA    1
NFL    2
NFL    2
NFL    2
```

My final output would just be col2 as I do not want to disclose col1, but i want to keep the rows associated by col2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [np.random.permutation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['MLB', 'MLB', 'NBA', 'NFL', 'NFL', 'NFL'],
                   [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]], index=['col1', 'col2']).T

# get all categories
cat = df['col1'].unique()
# shuffle them in random order
random_order = np.random.permutation(cat)

# define a mapping based on the random shuffle
map_dict = dict(zip(random_order, range(1, len(cat)+1)))

# change col2
out = df['col1'].replace(map_dict)
```